# Is the per-unit internal voltage equal to the ratio of field current to no-load field current?

Tags: voltage, current, generator, synchronous, synchronous-motor

An example problem provides the following information to solve for the field current.

[image]

The problem is below.

A large 60 Hz synchronous generator can be considered to be round rotor, that is, xd = xq = 2.0 per‐unit. Field current to achieve rated voltage while the stator is open circuited is Ifnl = 1000 A. Armature resistance is small enough that it can be ignored.
Assume the machine is initially operated as a generator with rated VA at a power factor of 0.8 per‐unit, current lagging (over‐excited). What field current is required?

I don't understand how the field current was found from the per-unit internal voltage. It seems like a huge jump. If someone could explain the in-between steps, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!